# find the maximum number of words in a sentence from a paragraph with C++

Tags: c++, string, sorting, max, std

I am trying to find out the maximum number of words in a sentence (Separated by a dot) from a paragraph. and I am completely stuck into how to sort and output to stdout.

Eg:
Given a string S: {"Program to split strings. By using custom split function. In C++"};

The expected output should be : 5

```
#define max 8 // define the max string  

string strings[max]; // define max string  
string words[max];
int count = 0;

 
void split (string str, char seperator)  // custom split() function 
{  
    int currIndex = 0, i = 0;  
    int startIndex = 0, endIndex = 0;  
    while (i <= str.size())  
    {  
        if (str[i] == seperator || i == str.size())  
        {  
            endIndex = i;  
            string subStr = "";  
            subStr.append(str, startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);  
            strings[currIndex] = subStr;  
            currIndex += 1;  
            startIndex = endIndex + 1;  
        }  
        i++;  
        }     
}  

void countWords(string str) // Count The words 
{
    int count = 0, i; 

    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0';i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
            count++;    
    }
 
    cout << "\n- Number of words in the string are: " << count +1 <<" -";
}

//Sort the array in descending order by the number of words
void sortByWordNumber(int num[30])
{
   /* CODE str::sort? std::*/
}

int main()  
{  
    string str = "Program to split strings. By using custom split function. In C++";  
    char seperator = '.'; // dot  
    int numberOfWords;
    
    split(str, seperator);  
    cout <<" The split string is: ";  
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)  
    {  
        cout << "\n initial array index: " << i << " " << strings[i];
        countWords(strings[i]);
        
    }  
    return 0;  
}
```

Count + 1 in countWords() is giving the numbers correctly only on the first result then it adds the " " whitespace to the word count.

Please take into consideration answering with the easiest solution to understand first. (std::sort, making a new function, lambda)

Comment: What are you going to sort? Your task is to find the maximum number of words in sentences.

Comment: Are there always a word between dots?  If so, then wouldn't the simplest thing to do would be to count the number of dots and add 1?  What does sample test data look like?

Comment: `int len(string str)  // length of the string ` - A `std::string` has a member function called `size()` that you can call to get the length of the string. There's also one called `length()` returning the same thing. So, instead of `len(str)`, do `str.size()`

Comment: Technically, I did find out the maximum number of words (though count+1 is throwing me off). i do not know how to output the solution to the stdout. in order to test it or to verify it. was thinking `std::sort of countWords()` or anything to show just that number (the maximum number of words). nothing else. In this case it should be 5.

Comment: @MpcHAG -- Now looking at your example, the code could be much simpler than what you have.  Basically a 4 line program using `std::stringstream` and a one line `while` loop.  There is no need for all of that `if` logic, `substr`, etc.

Comment: please show a [mre] with input, expected and actual output

Comment: @MpcHAG Also, what is the purpose of the `std::string` array's?  Unless you want to actually store the sentence words for some usage later on, you don't need them in the solution.  That maybe is what is getting others confused on what you want to output, since all you want to output is just the max number, not the actual words that are used.  Please look at using `std::stringstream`, and you will see how much cleaner the solution actually will be in comparison to what you have now.

Comment: @MpcHAG *Please take into consideration answering with the easiest solution to understand first* -- That is a matter of opinion to each person what is easy and what isn't -- what is easy to you or me could be difficult for someone else, and vice-versa.    The solutions given shouldn't take into consideration "ease", since again, "ease" is something that is personal to each one, not only yourself, but to others who are also looking for adequate answers.

Answer (score 3):

Your code does not make a sense. For example the meaning of this declaration

```
string strings[max];
```

is unclear.

And to find the maximum number of words in sentences of a paragraph there is no need to sort the sentences themselves by the number of words.

If I have understood correctly what you need is something like the following.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::string s;
    
    std::cout << "Enter a paragraph of sentences: ";
    
    std::getline( std::cin, s );
    
    size_t max_words = 0;
    
    std::istringstream is( s );
    std::string sentence;
    
    while ( std::getline( is, sentence, '.' ) )
    {
        std::istringstream iss( sentence );
    
        auto n = std::distance( std::istream_iterator<std::string>( iss ), 
                                std::istream_iterator<std::string>() );

        if ( max_words < n ) max_words = n;                             
    }
    
    std::cout << "The maximum number of words in sentences is " 
              << max_words <<  '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

If to enter the paragraph

```
Here is a paragraph. It contains several sentences. For example, how to use string streams.
```

then the output will be

```
The maximum number of words in sentences is 7
```

If you are not yet familiar with string streams then you could use member functions `find`, `find_first_of`, `find_first_not_of` with objects of the type `std::string` to split a string into sentences and to count words in a sentence.

Comment: `max_words = std::max(max_words, n);` should also work.

Comment: string streams are out of my league for the moment. but working on it. thanks,.

Comment: Nice, +1. One question though, how does `std::distance` work with `istream_iterator`. I'm missing "why" does this operation return the number of words. The second argument is the default (empty) string so I have no clue why in this case ++iter would hop from one word to the next, let alone why the empty string will stop this "hoping"

Comment: @LorahAttkins For stream input iterators it means the end of the input stream.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case sounds like a reduction. Essentially you can have a state machine (parser) that goes through the string and updates some state (e.g. counters) when it encounters the word and sentence delimiters. Special care should be given for corner cases, e.g. when having continuous multiple white-spaces or >1 continous full stops (`.`). A reduction handling these cases is shown below:

```
int max_words_in(std::string const& str)
{
    // p is the current and max word count.
    auto parser = [in_space = false] (std::pair<int, int> p, char c) mutable {
        switch (c) {
        case '.': // Sentence ends.
            if (!in_space && p.second <= p.first) p.second = p.first + 1;
            p.first = 0;
            in_space = true;
            break;
        case ' ': // Word ends.
            if (!in_space) ++p.first;
            in_space = true;
            break;
        default: // Other character encountered.
            in_space = false;
        }
        return p; // Return the updated accumulation value.
    };

    return std::accumulate(
        str.begin(), str.end(), std::make_pair(0, 0), parser).second;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8fc3100db6f26567)

The tricky part is deciding how to handle degenerate cases, e.g. what should the output be for `"This is a  , ,tricky ..  .. string to count"` where different types of delimiters alternate in arbitrary ways. Having a state machine implementation of the parsing logic allows you to easily adjust your solution (e.g. you can pass an "ignore list" to the parser and update the default case to not reset the `in_space` variable when `c` belongs to that list).

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
vector<string> split(string str, char seperator)  // custom split() function
{
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t seperator_pos = 0;

    vector<string> sentences;
    int word_count = 0;


    for (; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == seperator)
        {
            i++;
            sentences.push_back(str.substr(seperator_pos, i - seperator_pos));
            seperator_pos = i;
        }
    }


    if (str[str.size() - 1] != seperator)
    {
        sentences.push_back(str.substr(seperator_pos + 1, str.size() - seperator_pos));
    }

    return sentences;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript solution

```
var mostWordsFound = function(sentences) {
    let result = 0;

    sentences.forEach((item) => {
        length = item.split(' ').length
        result = result > length ? result : length;
    })

    return result;
};
```